# How can I use Ember Data custom api with json-api?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, json-api, jsonapi-resources

Before I use `json-api`, I custom ember data api like this:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import config from './../config/environment';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  ...

  useRepairPackage(repairPackageId) {
    Ember.$.ajax({url: `${config.host}/${config.namespace}/quotations/${this.get('id')}/use_repair_package.json`, type: "PATCH", data: {...}}).then((result)=> { 
      return this.reload();
    }); 
  }
});
```

But when I use `json-api`, `data: {...}` is more complex and I must make up json by myself.

It had best way to solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you use the JSONAPIAdapter for your application, you can still use `model.toJSON()` to return a flat data JSON object(uses JSONSerializer) to use anywhere like in your ajax request.

See [toJSON](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_toJSON).

P.S. Have you seen https://github.com/mike-north/ember-api-actions?